# python subprocess hangs when stderr is piped

Tags: java, python

I run a java program as a subprocess but when I redirect stderr to a pipe, the program hangs. For example `myProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)` works, but `myProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`hangs.

The command I run is something along the lines of:

```
java -DSomeVals -classpath <somevals> package.Name
```

Stderr generates massive amounts of output and I remember reading somewhere that with shell=True that might cause a deadlock. Unfortunately when i set shell=False, I get an error message that the file name is too long.

I tried `myProcess = subprocess.Popen(['java', args], shell=False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)`but then java complains that it can't find the class I'm trying to run.

I want to pipe stderr because it's cluttering the output of my program.

Comment: How are you processing the data from the pipe afterwards? Most of the python documentation says to use communicate, but if you *don't care* about what's coming out of stderr, then make it something like `stderr=open("/dev/null")` (don't actually do that, it will leak the file descriptor), Otherwise you need to use something like `communicate()` to slurp from both pipes to prevent the output from triggering a deadlock.

Comment: I call communicate, but only after the process has been running for about 5 minutes (it takes that long to produce the results I need). In the mean time the app is writing a log message every few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to read from the pipe. The pipe buffer is filling up and blocking the process. Checkout this example which repeats a "HelloWorld" 50,000 times.

```
import subprocess
import os

def getLinesFromShellCommand(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=os.getcwd())
    lines = []
    for curLine in p.stdout.readlines():
        lines.append(curLine)
    p.wait()
    return lines


print "Starting..."
lines = getLinesFromShellCommand("printf 'HelloWorld\n%.0s' {1..50000}")
for curLine in lines:
    print curLine,
```